# Beginner Python - Answering with either a string or a variable in a loop

Tags: python, string, while-loop, integer

My code so far:

```
prompt = "\nEnter 'quit' when you are finished."
prompt += "\nPlease enter your age: "

while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    age = int(age)

    if age == 'quit':
        break
    elif age <= 3:
        print("Your ticket is free")
    elif age <= 10:
        print("Your ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Your ticket is $15")
```

The program runs fine unless you enter 'quit' to end the loop. I understand that `age = int(age)` defines the user input as an integer. My question is how can I change it to to not treat 'quit' as an integer and end the loop when 'quit' is input.

Answer (score 1):

If `age` is `'quit'`, you will break anyway.  Therefore, you can just use `if` for the next one instead.  As long as you do that anyway, you can make it an int after that `if`:

```
while True:
    age = input(prompt)

    if age == 'quit':
        break
    age = int(age)

    if age <= 3:
        print("Your ticket is free")
    elif age <= 10:
        print("Your ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Your ticket is $15")
```

You should probably take care of those cases when the user types something else, however, so I would suggest the following:

```
while True:
    age = input(prompt)

    if age == 'quit':
        break
    elif not age.isdigit():
        print("invalid input")
        continue

    age = int(age)

    if age <= 3:
        print("Your ticket is free")
    elif age <= 10:
        print("Your ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Your ticket is $15")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a `try/except` here, actually.

The main goal of your application is to gather ages. So, wrap your input with a try/except to always get an integer. If you get a `ValueError`, you fall in to your exception block and check to see if you entered `quit`.

The application will tell the user it is quitting and break out. However, if the user did not enter `quit`, but some other string, you are told that the entry is invalid, and it will continue to ask the user for a valid age.

Also, just to make sure you never miss a 'quit' message that could be typed with different cases, you can always set the input to `lower` to always compare the same casing in your string. In other words, do `age.lower` when you are checking for the entry to be `quit`.

Here is a working demo:

```
prompt = "\nEnter 'quit' when you are finished."
prompt += "\nPlease enter your age: "

while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        if age.lower() == 'quit':
            print("Quitting your application")
            break
        else:
            print("You made an invalid entry")
            continue

    if age <= 3:
        print("Your ticket is free")
    elif age <= 10:
        print("Your ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Your ticket is $15")
```